# _redirect still continues php code execution

Tags: php, magento

I'm working on custom module and in my `IndexController.php` I'd written this function to add user to database

```
public function addAction() {
    if($this->getRequest()->getParam('name', '') == ''){
        $this->_redirect('etech/user');
        //die; or exit;
    }
    $form = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $user = Mage::getModel('test/test');
    foreach ($form as $key => $val){
        $user->setData($key, $val);
    }
    try{
        $user->save();
    }catch(Exception $e){
        print_r($e);
    }
    $this->_redirect('etech/user', array('msg'=>'success'));
}
```

I want to prevent users from accessing this url directly as `www.example.com/index.php/etech/user/add/`. For this I'd made a check `if($this->getRequest()->getParam('name', '') == ''){}`. The redirect is working well except the code in there keeps executing and user sees a success message which should not be seen. For this, I'd used old fashioned `exit` or `die` to stop executing the code then it doesn't even redirect.

What is the `magento` way to handle it? Also, as I'm using `getRequest()->getParams()`, it return both parameters either in `get` or `post`. Isn't any way out to get only `post` parametrs?

Comment: It is always suggested to use `die` or `exit` after redirect, but I, if the redirect is not working when you stop the script **after** the redirect, then the problem is probably somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct to use `$this->_redirect()`, but you must follow it up with a `return`, ideally `return $this;`.  You *could* also use `exit` or `die`, as you have been doing, but as I'm sure you know it would be better to let Magento do whatever it wants to do before redirecting you.

As long as you `return` immediately after `$this->_redirect()`, you won't have any issues.

**Edit:** And as for the request params question, <s>I *think* you can call something like `$this->getRequest()->getPostData()`</s> (that was false).  The general convention is to use `getParams()` regardless of whether the data was sent via GET or POST, because technically your code shouldn't be concerned about that.

**Edit #2:**
If the general convention doesn't apply and you desperately need to restrict access to your page based on POST vs. GET, here's a handy snippet from Mohammad:

```php
public function addAction()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        // echo 'post'; do your stuff
    } else {
        // echo 'get'; redirect
    }
}
```

Comment: I only meant, "I'm not sure if this is accurate." :-)

Comment: you right. there's no such method `getPostData()`. so it will not work. I'll need to check it manually in `$_POST`.

Comment: why isn't `exit` or `die` working there? have any idea?

Comment: I think `$this->_redirect()` doesn't call `header('Location: ...')` right away, so if you exit immediately then Magento doesn't get the opportunity to fully prepare the redirect.